# String Localisation in Android

Tags: android

How can one achieve string localisation in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation of string localization here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

However, if you want a sample of how to achieve it via code, visit [this link.](https://github.com/akhileshAwasthi/LocalizationSample)

Disclosure:  I have written the above mentioned sample.